# car dash with Android

Tags: android, canvas, photoshop, dashboard

I want create a car dashboard to use with an application written for Android OS. My application retrieves already the wanted data, but now I want to improve the appearance.

I can create a dashboard like this using photoshop.

[image: Dashboard]

My first question is, how can I rotate the needle to show the actual speed and rpm ? It's possible to do it with Canvas ?

Another question is, can I use the place in the middle to show other data like time elapsed or a map ? How ?

I hope you can help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the arrows in the picture and draw a red line for each programatically. And add a textbox/label over the display in the middle.

Comment: Nice to hear. Please accept answer if you're satisfied with it :-)

Answer (score 5):

1. Your needle can be done either by rotating a canvas in the onDraw method of a custom view. 
   Or you can make the needle a bitmap and rotate it using its matrix.

   [Link 1](http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html),
   [Link 2](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2009/10/rotating-bitmap-in-android.html)
2. Its hard to tell about your next question since we dont know what you need exactly. But the maps, location on maps can be done using the map activity.

   [Link 1](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html)
3. The time elapsed can be done by using a timer and a tamertask class that keeps updating the textview.

   [Link 1](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)